# Excel Standard devaition of the division between two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so I have two columns of numeric data in an excel table (A and B), each has 10 values. What I would like to do is to compute standard deviation of A divided by B.
somehthing like STDEV((A1:A5)/(B1:B5))

The difficulty is that it should be done by formula within a single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Formula `{=STDEV(A1:A5/B1:B5)}` will work if there are no 0 values in `B1:B5`. But it must be inputted as an array formula. Input it into the cell without the curly brackets and the press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to confirm. The curly brackets should then appear automatically.